# Why do my speakers not mute when I plug in headphones?

Tags: windows-8, audio, speakers, headphones

For some strange reason Windows 8 'merges' my speakers with my headphones. When I go to "Playback devices" by clicking on the volume icon on the bottom right of my screen, it only shows "Speakers/Headphones". As a result of this, when I plugin my headphones, both my headphones and speakers output sound.

How do I make it so when I plug in my headphones, my speakers mute?

Comment: Has it worked before? Dekstop or laptop? Brand and model/motherboard model?

Comment: are you inserting the jack all the way in? try gently rotating it to see if its a matter of loose connector.

Comment: @Lorenzo Von Matterhorn On my other laptop which is like a HP Pavilion worked, I triple checked the jacks they are fine, im using a HP ENVY 20 TouchSmart PC

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn It goes through the headphone and the speaker. I'm commenting because the OP lost 'ownership' of this question when he registered thus cannot comment anymore.

Comment: Use the `Find and fix audio playback problems` in the control panel. May have to run it more than once to fix playback with both the jacks and internal speakers. Sometimes can fix output problems.

Answer (score 1):

Reading all I can say this your problem is that you're assuming *similar* machines are also *similar* in how they manage sound internally.

This isn't true. Different computers can have different sound chips. And different sound chips have different ways of separating sound to different outputs. Also, you might have set up things differently in both machines.

From experience, you can check your machine's documentation and check if there exists any option inside the BIOS that enables that physical separation. As this is coupled with how the sound drivers work, there can also be something in the sound driver's documentation about it.

Ultimately, you might have the bad luck that there is no redirection (i.e. the sound signal is simply passed to both output devices at once). This last one seems less likely, as it can be perfectly conceived that one would use a better pair of headphones rather that the usual inbuilt speakers.

<sub>(I'll search a little more but since there exists a plethora of drivers and chips, I can't test accordingly)</sub>

Comment: I'm having some trouble getting any sort of documentation for the audio drivers, at least from HP. From what I've seen, they use an "IDT High Definition Audio Driver" but I've not seen any sort of documentation inside the package...